# AWS EC2 instance is working but can't connect to it via browser

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a nodejs app running on an EC2 instance. I installed the webapp using Ubuntu server 18.04 and node version v16.x using this link:

[Node installation guide v16.x](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions)

To run the project I used the following tutorial: [Tutorial link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/977/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-application-on-aws-ec2-server)

The problem I am facing is that when I run the starting command `npm start` my app launches on the server using port 3000. But whenever I open the link provided from AWS which in my case is : `https://ec2-3-72-79-132.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com` it doesn't respond. I saw some similar questions and most common answers were to edit the inbound security groups which I did.

[image]

But it still doesn't work. I also tried to access the link with http only like this:

> `http://ec2-3-72-79-132.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000` but it still doesn't work. Any help will be highly appreciated, because I spent 2 days struggling with this issue and I see that I don't make any progress.

Comment: You need to open port `3000` to everyone (meaning `0.0.0.0/0`) to receive web requests.

Comment: I usually don't like to criticize people for their work, but this tutorial is bad. You don't need all those security group rules, most of them are doing nothing. In fact, if this would be production, your backend would be considered insecure.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I am beginner and I just started to learn AWS. If you can give me some advice about other tutorial will be very appreciated or at least tell me how to make it more secure.

Comment: To make it securely accessible only allow 3000 over https for your public ip only. You can search over google for "my public ip" and you will get your public ip allocated by your ISP.  Otherwise whilelist the client's ip which are going to access the app.